# Programmable Search Element Paid API React

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a search engine based on Programmable Search Element Paid API. I create website with search engine in Programmable Search Element and I put this website to iframes

```
const Iframes = () => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const query = window.location.search.slice(3, window.location.search.length);
            const url = `https://cse.google.com/cse?q=${query}&cx=XXX#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=${query}&gsc.page=1`;
            setUrl(url);
        }

    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <iframe src={url}></iframe>
        </div >

    );
};
```

]

But I have problem with cors:

**Refused to display 'https://cse.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.**

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at XXX from origin XXX has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but since nobody else has answered, I'll give you my thoughts: The relevant CORS policy was created by Google, and can not be altered by you. They set it so only cse.google.com can display it in a frame. But from what I can tell, you don't need to put it in an iframe anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  how can I display this page at my address without using iframes?

Comment: The first code example on this page should help you: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element. Place the script in your index.html and the `gcse-search` element inside the div in the code you posted in your question.